# WebView not creating object from imported file

Tags: nativescript

The problem is that I'm not being able to do this:

```html
<script src="./app/node_modules/tone/build/Tone.js"></script> 

<script>

  var synth = new Tone.Synth();

</script>
```

I get this in the console output:

chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(50)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: Tone is not defined"

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What could be wrong here:**

1. WebView would not understand that path at all.
2. `node_modules` folder won't be available after compilation.

**So what you could do**

1. Place your JS file within the same folder where you have your HTML, so you can use relative path.
2. If you use Webpack make sure the configuration is updated to include those HTML and JS files during build.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply. I have done the first step, but I don't know where to include the HTML and JS in the Webpack. Would you , please, tell me how should I do it? I am using vanilla project .

Comment: You may create a folder named "www" inside app folder, place your webview related content (HTML, CSS, JS etc.,) there and update CopyWebpackPlugin in webpack.config.js file to pickup those files. You will already have an example in that file for copying fonts, images, just add a entry for "www" folder you created. So it will be available inside your application directory at run time.

Comment: Here is what I did: I created a folder called www inside app folder and added the following line to the webpack.config.js: { from: "www/**" }. I also removed the the platform folder and rebuilt the project. From all of this I got the same result wich is chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(50)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: Tone is not defined".

Comment: Were you able to reproduce the issue with Playground?

Comment: No, I was not. There is something new I have noticed. The Tone.js module has this line: var _ = require('lodash'); And in the console I'm getting: "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined". I know nativescript uses CommonJS. So what is going on here. Any clue? Thank you.

Comment: require is something won't available in browser environment, make sure you browserify that module along with all it's dependencies.

Comment: I got rid of the require error using browserify, but I'm still getting the  [INFO:CONSOLE(50)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: Tone is not defined"

Comment: Make sure Tone is defined as global variable under window object. If you can put all together in Playground, it will be easy to take a look.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked! I'd like to say that you were very patient with me and for that I really appreciate it. I had to do all the steps you recommended to get to the solution. Thank you once again.